# TSQL - Detect Null Column Condition On DateTime, Calc 24 Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following example dynamic SQL in a stored proc, the parameters are a linked server and the database I am connecting to via the procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[DateTest] 
    @LINKED_SERVER_NAME nvarchar(max),
    @DATABASE_NAME nvarchar(max)
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON 

BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT [TEST], [DATE_TIME_1], [DATE_TIME_2]  
FROM [' + @LINKED_SERVER_NAME + '].[' + @DATABASE_NAME + '].[dbo].[EXAMPLE_TABLE]'

EXEC (@SQL)
COMMIT
```

I am trying to get the records for the last 24 hours by using the DATE_TIME_1 Value. This is no problem by adding this to the above:

```
WHERE DATE_TIME_1 >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

However, sometimes, the date that I am supposed to be using for this clause is DATE_TIME_2. This condition is when the DATE_TIME_1 is NULL.

In summary, if DATE_TIME_1 is not null, see if it has occurred in the last 24 hours. If DATE_TIME_1 is null, use DATE_TIME_2 as the argument to see if it occurred in the last 24 hours. The problem I am having is I am sorta lost on how to write the IF condition in the above.

Comment: Take a look at `coalesce.`

Comment: Not to sound like a dink but `NVARCHAR(MAX)` might be a little overkill for those server and database name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add case statement:

```
....
WHERE case when DATE_TIME_1 is null then DATE_TIME_2 Else DATE_TIME_1 End >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

or

sql server specific:

```
WHERE  IsNull(DATE_TIME_1, DATE_TIME_2)  >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```